# Where to implement functions from an interface's parent interface?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm asked to implement an interface and I'm wondering what would be the best strategy to factorize the code as much as possible.

Here is the interface definition (I'm not supposed to change it):

```
#include <string>

class BaseIf
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseIf() {}

    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
};

class IntIf : public BaseIf
{
public:
    virtual ~IntIf() {}

    virtual int getValue() = 0;
};

class FloatIf : public BaseIf
{
public:
    virtual ~FloatIf() {}

    virtual float getValue() = 0;
};
```

I'll end up with `IntImpl` (implementing `IntIf`) and `FloatImpl` (implementing `FloatIf`). But I'm wondering where I should put any code common to those two classes (like the `name` attribute management or any other stuff required by `BaseIf` which is actually much bigger than in this MCVE).

If I create `BaseImpl` (implementing `BaseIf`'s `getName` function) with the common code, and have `IntImpl` derive from it (and `IntIf`), then I need to also implement `getName` in it because it's reported as not implemented. And I also get double inheritance of `BaseIf`...

I was wondering if Pimpl pattern would help, then `IntImpl` would have a `BaseImpl` object as attribute (and only derive from `IntIf`), but then, again, I need to implement `getName` in `IntImpl` to "forward" the call to the `BaseImpl` attribute. So as `BaseIf` has actually many virtual functions this is just going to be a real pain to maintain.

Is there no smart solution/pattern making it possible to implement once only `getName` in a common place? Or is it just the interface that is bad and should be reworked?

Comment: Depending on the rest of your requirements and design, it seems that a better choice would have been templates and template specialization here. Or possibly a generic "Number" template without any specialization or inheritance at all.

Comment: Regarding your current code, unless you plat to have multiple "Int" implementations all inheriting from `IntIf`, there's really no need for separate interface and implementation classes for "Int".

Comment: I would suggest that implementing ***derived*** interfaces that still maintain a pure virtual member is 'bad design'. As others have said, templates would work better, here (but, you cant change the design, apparently).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The original interfaces are much more complex and connot easily be templatized (they handle `int`, `float`, but also `string` and `bool`, and vector of `int`/`float`/`string`...). Actually `InfIt` and `FloatIf` are very different, but I simplified it here.

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, and as commented, it's much more complex. I also have the feeling that the derived interface is a bad idea, but It looks so simple and valid when you see it that I'm surprised it can become problematic when you try to implement it...

Comment: Adding derived interfaces is just plain daft. IMHO, it totally undermines the whole point of the interface paradigm. You would normally derive ***usable*** classes from your interface - but there are, occasionally, perhaps, times when an 'intermediate' may be helpful. Here, such an intermediate would define the `getName` member, for example.

Comment: @Adrian: By "intermediate", do you mean that `IntIf` and `FloatIf` should have `BaseImpl` as parent? Is there some good/bad practices when defining interfaces?

Comment: *Why* is the handling of the different "types" different? Especially, why are there such big differences between the handling for `float` and `int`? From a mathematical point of view there's really not that much difference between integers and real (`float`) numbers, what is the design decision or requirements that leads to the big differences in your implementation? To me it seems like a problem with requirement analysis and the resulting design.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: As an example, `FloatIf` would have some information about how the value should be displayed (how many decimals), `IntIf` would not.

Comment: And I really see no use for a `BaseImpl` class, aren't the purpose to inherit the *interface* from the abstract (interface) base classes?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Did not understand this last comment...sorry.

Comment: Displaying "values" is a really minor part, and if the other parts of your classes does things like addition, subtraction, etc. then you're just duplicating a lot of code that could be generalized and shared between the implementations.

Comment: Personally, I would make `getName` real (not pure virtual) in `BaseIf` and add a pure virtual `getValue` to that. Then stuffs like `IntIf` would be so much simpler. But - like the man says - you can't change stuff that you can't change.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Let's forget `IntIf` and `FloatIf`, Let's call them `AIf` with virtual function `doSomething` and `BIf` with virtual function `doSomethingElse`...

Comment: This is why virtual inheritance was invented. Make all inheritance (of pure interfaces only if you want) virtual and all the errors disappear. [Demo](https://ideone.com/2qQg0a).

Comment: OK - If I was offered this task, to implement ***without changing the definition***, then I would (prefer to) remain unemployed rather than taking on the job (whatever the remuneration level).

Comment: @n.m.: That's just perfect, a very easy way to modify the interface without modifying the whole architecture. If you post this as a real answer (and if there is no better by tehn) I 'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @Adrian: Actually, I defined the interface ;-) I can change it...but I wanted to understand if the interface was really badly defined or if I was just not good enough to implement it smartly ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a template class that implements the common part of an interface like this:

```
template <class IFACE> class BaseImpl : public IFACE
{
    public:
    std::string getName () override { ... }
}
```

and then

```
class IntImpl : public BaseImpl<IntIf>
{
    public:
    int getValue() override { ... }
}
```

The result is a simple single-inheritance chain. `BaseIf` <- `IntIf` <- `BaseImpl` <- `IntImpl`

Make sure you have a good reason for `IntIf` and `FloatIf` to exist, though -- in your MCVE they look like they don't need to be there at all.

Comment: Great! That's the only answer fixing the problem (have `getName` be implemented once) without changing the interface at all. As commented in the OP, `IntIf` and `FloatIf` were just examples for my MCVE. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is the primary use case for virtual inheritance.

Despite all the stigma that surrionds multiple and virtual inheritance, there are no particular problems when oure interfaces (no data members) are virtually inherited. Here's the gist:

```
class BaseIf
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseIf() {}

    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
};

class IntIf : public virtual BaseIf
{
public:
    virtual ~IntIf() {}

    virtual int getValue() = 0;
};

class BaseImpl : public virtual BaseIf
{
  public:
    std::string getName () override { return "whoa dude"; }
};

class IntImpl : public virtual IntIf, public BaseImpl
{
  public:
    int getValue() override { return 42; }
};
```

[full demo](https://ideone.com/2qQg0a)

With a deeper hierarchy one probably would have to virtually inherit implementation classes as well, which is not very convenient but still doable.

An alternative to virtual inheritance of implementation would be to stratify the implementation into a "building blocks" layer and the final layer. Building blocks are standalone and do not inherit other building blocks. (They may inherit interfaces). The final classes inherit building blocks but not other final classes.

```
class BaseBlock : public virtual BaseIf
{
  public:
    std::string getName () override { return "whoa dude"; }
};

class IntBlock : public virtual IntIf
{
  public:
    int getValue() override { return 42; }
};

class BaseImpl : public BaseBlock {};

class IntImpl : public BaseBlock, public IntBlock {};
```

[full demo](https://ideone.com/FXxQLm)

One does need to made changes to the interfaces if there was no virtual inheritance in the hierarchy. These changes are however transparent (the clients code need not be changed, only recompiled) and probably beneficial anyway.

Without virtual inheritance, one would have to resort to lots of boilerplate.

```
class BaseBlock // no base class!
{
  public:
    virtual std::string getName () { return "whoa dude"; }
};

class BaseImpl : public BaseIf, public BaseBlock
{
  public:
    // oops, getName would be ambiguous here, need boplerplate
    std::string getName () override { return BaseBlock::getName(); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You may want to mention that you propose to modify the interface because it is definitely ill formed if virtual inheritance was omitted (if that's what you believe) and there will be no nice way to implement it the way it is declared? As my OP mentioned that the first intent was not to change the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide default implementation for pure virtual functions:

```
struct A {
    virtual void frob() = 0;
};

void A::frob() {
    std::cout << "default";
}

struct B : A {
    void frob() override {
        A::frob(); // calls the default
    }
};
```

If I'm reading your problem correctly, you'd like a default implementation for `getName()`. So solve that, simply provide an implementation and call it:

```
class IntIf : public BaseIf
{
public:
    virtual ~IntIf() {}
    virtual int getValue() = 0;

    std::string getName() override {
        return BaseIf::getName();
    }
};

class FloatIf : public BaseIf
{
public:
    virtual ~FloatIf() {}
    virtual float getValue() = 0;

    std::string getName() override {
        return BaseIf::getName();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but if BaseIf has many functions, they will end up duplicated in every child class, that's what I wanted to avoid.